# React: I want to send my Add component form inputs to my Browse component to be viewed

Tags: reactjs

Thank you so much @spakmad and @Leon Bogod for your swift responses, definitely made some progress.

However, when I type in my information it appears in real time, then when I click submit it disappears. I don't mind the info appearing live, but I want it to save, so i can add more in the future.

Browse (Parent) component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Add from "./Add";

class Browse extends Component {

  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      name: "",
      time: "",
      ingredients: [],
      directions: []
  };

  this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
  this.handleTimeChange = this.handleTimeChange.bind(this);
  this.handleIngredientsChange = this.handleIngredientsChange.bind(this);
  this.handleDirectionsChange = this.handleDirectionsChange.bind(this);
}

  handleNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleTimeChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      time: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleIngredientsChange (event) {
    this.setState({
      ingredients: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleDirectionsChange (event) {
    this.setState({
      directions: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Add
          handleName={this.handleNameChange}
          handleTime={this.handleTimeChange}
          handleDirections={this.handleDirectionsChange}
          handleIngredients={this.handleIngredientsChange}
        />
        {this.state.name}
        {this.state.time}
        {this.state.ingredients}
        {this.state.directions}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Browse;
```

Browse (Child) component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Browse from "./App";
import './Add.css';


class Add extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
      render() {
        return (
          <div id="container">
            <h2>Add</h2>
            <form>
                <br/>
        {/*NAME*/}
              <input
                name="name"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Name"
                onChange={this.props.handleName}
                />
                <br/>
                <br/>
        {/*TIME*/}
              <label>Duration of recipe</label>
                <br/>
              <select
                name="time"
                onChange={this.props.handleTime}
                >
                <option value="Null">Select</option>
                <option value="Less than an hour">Less than an hour</option>
                <option value="1 to 2 hours">1 to 2 hours</option>
                <option value="2 to 3 hours">2 to 3 hours</option>
                <option value="3 or more hours">3 or more hours</option>
              </select>
                <br/>
                <br/>
    {/*INGREDIENTS*/}
              <label>Ingredients</label>
                <br/>
              <textarea
                placeholder="Please list ingredients here."
                name="ingredients"
                type="textarea"
                rows="10"
                cols="30"
                onChange={this.props.handleIngredients}
                />
                <br/>
                <br/>
    {/*DIRECTIONS*/}
              <label>Directions</label>
                <br/>
              <textarea
                placeholder="Please list directions here."
                name="directions"
                type="textarea"
                rows="10"
                cols="30"
                onChange={this.props.handleDirections}
                />
                <br/>
                <br/>
       {/*SUBMIT*/}
              <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
          </div>
        )
  }
}

export default Add;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Add` component depends on data in the form of:

```
{
 name: "",
 time: "",
 ingredients: [],
 directions: []
}
```

At the parent component, in this case `Browse`, you want to display a list of recipes. For each recipe you want to display you need a new data object in the form above. In `Browse` you can define an Array of Objects representing each recipe. Once these recipes are defined in an Array you can map over them, and for each one render an `Add` component with the respective data. Then, only render a `Browse` component in your `<div id='container' />`.

To maintain an ability to edit all aspects of these recipes, you'll need to define the change handlers in the `Browse` component, and pass them down to the `Add` components as `props`. The reason they need to be defined in `Browse` is because `Browse` holds the state of the list of recipes, and whenever a change occurs you need to update the state of that list in `Browse`. `"name"` should be a unique identifier of each recipe, or another attribute will be needed for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

So in your child component which is add you must pass name , time and ingrideints so you can then access them in parent component. also the change handlers must be passed down as props.

```
 <Add
  name = {this.state.name}
  time ={this.state.time} 
  ingredients={this.state.ingrdients}
  directions={this.state.directions}/>
```

because ingreidents and directions is an array you will have to use map to get all the data so  you should do something like this

```
 {this.props.indgridents.map( ( ingrident, index ) => {
        return <p key={ `ingridient-${ index }` }>{ ingrideitn }</p>;
      })}
```